# Way to set off duplicate row effected in Sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am calculating effected rows after executing a query in .Net

```
rowEffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

But my sql shows duplicate rows being effected after executing the query. 
It shows same result 4 times so rowEffected  = 4  instead of 1
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GF4n4.png)

Is there is way to set off duplicate rows being effected in SQL??

Comment: You should provide information about your query, and how you call it, because the issue looks to be more with your implementation.

Comment: Please provide full detail about your whole scenario.post your question with steps.Another thing ExecuteNonQuery() will return total affected rows.it will help you to define whether your records are duplicate or not.i insist you should also put tag C# or Asp.net Whatever you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you query is a single statement, it seems you have a one or more triggers on the table that are returning the extraneous row counts.  Add `SET NOCOUNT ON` to the trigger code to suppress counts of rows affected by the trigger.